# javafx tableview how to get the row I clicked?

Tags: javafx

here is my code

```
// this event is attached to TableCell
public EventHandler dblclickDescription = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if(event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
            if(event.getClickCount() == 2){
                printRow(event.getTarget());
            }
        }
        event.consume();
    }
};

// print row
public void printRow(Object o){
    Text text = (Text) o;

    // ??? don't know what to write here

   System.out.println(row.toString());
}
```

1) how do I get from the cell I clicked to the row?

2) can I attach the event to the whole row instead of each column?

EDIT:
3) I thought that I attached the event on `TableCell`

```
TableCell cell = TableColumn.DEFAULT_CELL_FACTORY.call(p);
cell.setOnMouseClicked(dblclickDescription);
```

but when I tested,

```
event.getSource();// is a TableColumn
event.getTarget();// is a Text if clicked on text
event.getTarget();// is a TableColumn if clicked on empty space, even if that cell has text
```

is there a way to get `TableCell` from `MouseEvent`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To answer your specific questions:

> how do I get from the cell I clicked to the row?

`TableCell` defines a [`getTableRow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html#getTableRow--) method, returning the `TableRow`. So you can do

```
Object item = cell.getTableRow().getItem();
```

which will give you the row item from the table (i.e. the correct element of `table.getItems()`). You can also get this from `table.getItems().get(cell.getIndex())` if you prefer.

> can I attach the event to the whole row instead of each column?

Yes. Define a `rowFactory`:

```
TableView<MyDataType> table = new TableView<>();

table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<MyDataType> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if (! row.isEmpty() && event.getButton()==MouseButton.PRIMARY 
             && event.getClickCount() == 2) {

            MyDataType clickedRow = row.getItem();
            printRow(clickedRow);
        }
    });
    return row ;
});

// ...

private void printRow(MyDataType item) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: wow, two lambda expressions, guess I really need to learn it quick.

Answer (score 5):

To get back the index of the row or the selected item, use this code :

```
Object object =  table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().get();
int index = table.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().get();
```

Then you can add a listener when the index / object change like this :

```
table.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((num) -> function());
```

Comment: "Selection" is semantically different to "clicking on a cell" though. This approach is likely to work, but it's really a bit fragile. How do you know that  the selection state will be updated *before* your cell listener is invoked. Do you really want the action to be performed if the user changes selection with the keyboard (which it will with this solution): the original question is solely about mouse clicks on cells.

Comment: Additionally, if the user clicks on a cell in one row, and then double clicks on another cell in the same row, the change listener will not be fired...