# How to check if checkbox is checked in a specific row?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-checkbox

I generated a table which has checkboxes at the end of every row. I want to sum all of values in the specific row if the checkbox is selected in that row. Therefore I need to check if the checkbox is checked in that specific row. So far I have this:

```
btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<rowNumber; i++) {
                if(cb.isChecked()) {
                    sum = sum + rowSums[i];
                }
            }
            txtResult.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
});
```

Normally, I can access the values of all cells withing a row and I am able to sum all of those values inside the row. However, when I add if statement inside the sum, I always get 0. I know what is the problem. I know I have to check if the checkbox is checked in that specific row. But I don't know how to do that.
By the way I also set IDs for every checkboxes inside the row. For example, ID of the first row's checkbox is 0 and the second row's is 1 and so on. So I just have to access that specific checkbox and check if it is checked.

**EDIT (SOLVED)**
I stored every checkboxes inside a `CheckBox` array. Then in my for loop, I called that specific `CheckBox` and it worked fine.

```
private CheckBox cb;
private CheckBox [] cbs;
```

In the for loop:

```
cbs[i] = cb;
```

And my for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<rowNumber; i++) {
   if(cbs[i].isChecked()) {
      sum = sum + rowSums[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: Do not use id = 0 for you views, as it means 'no id' to Android.

Comment: oh thanks for the tip. I am going to change it now. I am just looking a method like to grab that specific checkbox with the id of the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

You can create a listener for the checkboxes so that when any checkbox is checked/unchecked add/delete the corresponding data to the calculation.

`OR:`

You can give all the checkboxes ids, and then store the ids in an array in the class like:

```
    //as a class attribute 
    Int[]checkboxesIds = new array[] {ids in xml};  
    //in the loop
    CheckBox ch = findViewById(ids[i])
    ch.ischecked();
```

but its wrong for large of data.

Comment: Actually,
    `CheckBox ch = findViewById(ids[i])`
part could work for me but I still am not sure how to get the checkbox in that specific row. I am looking something like
    `cb.getCheckbox(id)`
which selects the checkbox that I need.

Comment: did you use tableview? is so try to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191264/javafx-tableview-how-to-get-the-row-i-clicked